# Extrair item de objeto JSON com Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, json, array, google-maps, http

Tenho uma aplicação em Angular que usa a API do Google Maps para buscar latitude e longitude, porém não estou conseguindo pegar a latitude e a longitude separadamente.

Minha aplicação funciona da seguinte maneira, o usuário digita o CEP e o sistema usando a API do ViaCEP carrega todos os dados do endereço, também a partir do CEP o sistema usa a API do Google para pegar a longitude e latitude

**Controller**

```
.controller("enderecoCtrl", enderecoCtrl);

  enderecoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'CepService', 'LatLongService'];
  function enderecoCtrl($scope, CepService, LatLongService) {
    $scope.app = "Endereço";
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.salvar = function(endereco) {

      $scope.model = {
        endereco: $scope.endereco.cep
      };

      CepService.getCep($scope.model).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.valorEndereco = data;
        console.log(data);
        $scope.erroCep = false;

      }).error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.erroCep = true;
        console.log("Cep");
        console.log(status);
      });

      LatLongService.getLatLong($scope.model).success(function(data, status){
        var addresses = [];
        angular.forEach(data.results, function(item){
              angular.forEach(item.geometry.location, function(item){
                addresses.push(item);
            });
          return addresses;
        });
        $scope.latLong = addresses;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(addresses);
      });
    };
```

**SERVICES**

```
    module.factory('CepService', function($http) {

    var getCep = function(model) {
      return $http({
        url: "http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + model.endereco + "/json",
        method: "get"
      });
    };
    return {
      getCep: getCep
    };
  });


module.factory('LatLongService', function($http){

    var getLatLong = function(model){
      return $http({
        url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+ model.endereco + "&sensor=false&region=$region",
        method: "get"
      });
    };
    return {
      getLatLong: getLatLong
    };
});
```

**RESULTADO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode-se notar que vem a latitude e longitude juntas em apenas um Array, gostaria que elas viessem separadas.

Obs.: Essa aplicação é uma aplicação de aprendizado, porém tenho um caso real para implementar essas duas API no meu trabalho, por isso o uso do ViaCEP quando eu poderia usar apenas a do Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pode tentar isso dentro do teu success

```
     LatLongService.getLatLong($scope.model).success(function(data, status){
        var addresses = [];
        angular.forEach(data.results, function(item){
           addresses.push({latitude: item[0], longitude: item[1]});
        });
        $scope.latLong = addresses;
      });
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém resolvi passar os valores sem dar push em um array e funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode acessar cada item do array usando índices, por ex.: `objeto.propriedade[0]` para o primeiro item e `objeto.propriedade[1]` para o segundo.

Com isso você pode criar duas variáveis, `longitude` e `latitude` e atribuir os valores a elas, ou até mesmo criar novas propriedades no objeto que deve conter esses dados: `objeto.latitude = objeto.results[0]` e `objeto.longitude = objeto.results[1]`.

Comment: Tanto a sua quanto a resposta do Pedro estão corretas, me ajudaram bastante. Obrigado